# Sci-Fi book with girl who spent 3 years in space

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

#### Major Plot Points

- A girl (the main character) has spent the last 3 years in space, I think because she had training of some sort.
- When she comes back to her planet (starts with "V," I think), she finds some of the species on her planet (who were previously peaceful) fighting each other.
- Another creature is leading a rebellion against the humans that have property, including the main character (name starts with an "S"?).

#### Time

- **Setting:** Future, for sure
- **Read:** Probably around 2008, but that is probably a lot later than it was published
- **Estimated Publication:** 1960?

#### Author

- No idea, whatsoever!
- **Not** Isaac Asimov, Ray Bradbury, or George Orwell...

#### Other Details

- **Language:** English

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @Valorum Unfortunately, this is everything I can remember!

Comment: I find that hard to believe. What language was the story in? Was it a hardback or paperback book? What age was the "girl"? Was it a story for adults or for kids? Was the fighting described in extravangantly gory detail? How did she get into space in the first place?

Comment: @Valorum The only question of those that I can answer with certainty is its language, which I have edited into my question. For the others, I have no clue...

Comment: Define 'girl' please...is it a pre-teen like the kids in Ender's Game? Or an early twenties? (I'm trying to suss out if it was a YA type book)

Comment: @DannyMcG Probably a girl in her teens. 15? Around there...

Comment: What was she doing in space for 3 years?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Ah! Previously (refer to 3rd and 4th comments in chain), I couldn't remember. Now, it seems to be coming back to me! I'll edit it in...

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I do know what tags are for, thanks. In practice, most story-id tagging go one "media" tag (it's especially more helpful to have [novel] than [books], anyway). By that logic, you'd want to retagging every [novel] question with [books]... I won't engage in a petty war over such a "matter", but I do think bumping that back for redundant tagging was overly unnecessary.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath (1/2) round and round in circles we go; I could reply the exact same comment as I wrote above. Redundancy in tags is something I'd reject as "no improvement whatsoever" in a suggested edit. Like I said I won't go into a petty edit war, but as you came at me teaching me your views on this, I naturally expressed mine back. It's fine, we can disagree on things and none of us is really wrong or right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## *The Gray Prince* (1974) by Jack Vance

It is actually a complete coincidence that I found this. I was searching through my local library's catalog for science fiction books in hopes of getting one during my next visit. There it was! The title seemed familiar and I thought the title was interesting so I went ahead and clicked on it!

---

The main character's name is **Schaine Madduc** and her home planet is **Koryphon** (which doesn't start with a "V"!). She actually spent **5 years** in space and, when she comes back, it's all rebellion, rebellion, rebellion! Here are the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gray_Prince) and [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/839011.The_Gray_Prince) pages for anyone who is interested!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know that book, but I never would have gotten this answer right.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank Fate. This was a complete coincidence! :)